# How to print an incremented number after every loop in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to python, but I've made a lot of progress over the last few days. The below script works fine, but I just can't figure out how implement code that would print an incremented number every time 'avail' is equal to NO. I'd like to have it print something like 'None Available 1' on the first loop, then 'None Available 2' on the second loop, then 'None Available 3' on the third loop, etc..

```
import requests
import time
import subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('Server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):
    avail = soup.find('span', id='availability').text.strip()
    if avail == "YES":
        return True
    elif avail == "NO":
        print('None Available')
        return False
    else:
        print("Unexpected value")
        return None

def main():
    url ='https://www.blahblah.com'

    while True:
        is_available = get_detail_data(get_page(url))
        if is_available:
            subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\filename.bat"], shell=False)
            break
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Put a counter and increment the counter

Comment: I notice that you are already printing out "None Available" in the `get_detail_data` function.  Is that where you're looking to print out "None Available 1", etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The following would probably work, but there might be a better way to structure it.

```
_not_avail_counter = 0
def get_detail_data(soup):
    avail = soup.find('span', id='availability').text.strip()
    if avail == "YES":
        return True
    elif avail == "NO":
        _not_avail_counter += 1
        print('None Available ' + str(_not_avail_counter))
        return False
    else:
        print("Unexpected value")
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your `while True` loop into a `for` loop on an `itertools.count` iterator. You can pass the value from the count to the `get_detail_data` function with an argument.

```
import itertools

def get_detail_data(soup, count):         # take the count as an argument
    avail = soup.find('span', id='availability').text.strip()
    if ...
        # ...
    elif avail == "NO":
        print('None Available', count)    # include count here (and anywhere else you want)
        # ...

def main():
    url ='https://www.blahblah.com'

    for c in itertools.count():           # produce the count in a loop
        is_available = get_detail_data(get_page(url), c)

        # ...
```

Note that `itertools.count` starts counting a zero. If you want to start at 1 (like a human usually would when counting things), you may want to pass `1` as the `start` argument: `for c in itertools.count(1)`.